# Observable xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a project where I read a xml document into memory. Then I populate an observable collection with the data. In the project I have modules that all can change the data coming from the xml document. Seem to me that there should be away to get rid of the observable collection and work directly on the xml document and still get change notifications when elements and properties change. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is [XML data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287.aspx). Check out the [XMLDataProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx) from the .NET framework, especially the `DataChanged` and `PropertyChanged events`.

Warning: I linked to the 4.0 versions. If you're using anything older than Visual Studio 2010, change the framework version in the MSDN pages.